# switching between list (transition matrix)

Tags: python, transition, hidden-markov-models

I have a problem to calculate the transition probabilities of people changing jobs. In the example below (which is a pivot table). Individiual `7` has different jobs in different years with different employers. I need to calculate the probability of this person changing job.

pivot table is generated from raw data (bottom of this question) as follow:

```
newdf.pivot_table(columns=['employers'], index=['indviduals','year'], fill_value=0, aggfunc=len)



     employers     1    7   12  13  15  22  23  27  28  45  99
indviduals  year                                            
7          2000    1    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
           2001    0    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
           2002    0    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
           2004    0    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
           2005    0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
           2006    0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
           2009    0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
12         1999    0    0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
           2001    0    0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
           2006    0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
           2012    0    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Here is what I have tried in python:

transitions=newdf['employers']

```
n=1+max(transitions)
M = [[0]*n for _ in range(n)]
for (i, j) in zip(transitions, newdf['indviduals'][1:]):
       M[i][j] +=1 #this generates list out of index error.
```

This is an obvious error because I am trying to match the list of unequal length.

second attempt is

```
counts=newdf.groupby('individual')['employer'].value_counts()

(counts/counts.sum())
```

this is not going to give me the state of change from employer to employer.

## RAW DATA

```
import pandas as pd

newd = {'year': [2001, 2002, 2005, 2002, 2004, 1999, 2000, 1999, 2012, 2000, 2010, 2005, 2006, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2001, 2001,
                 2004, 2001, 2002, 2006, 2009,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005],
     'indviduals': [12, 23, 24, 28,30, 12,7, 12, 12, 23, 24, 7, 12, 35, 39,37, 36, 333, 13, 15, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 12, 13, 15, 28,30],
     'employers': [12, 23, 28, 22, 12, 12,1, 12, 12, 23, 27, 45, 99, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 15, 13, 22, 15, 23, 28, 45, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13] }

newdf=pd.DataFrame(newd)
```

Comment: Any chance you can provide the code which creates your table, so we can test solutions on our own machines?

Comment: marco_gorelli I have added raw data

Comment: Thanks. If you could also post your desired output, that'd be great!